# Heroku gives internal server error on only one of three actions on my api app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, heroku, internal-server-error

I've built an api which serves 3 different collections of data when called. Each collection is different category, namely: restaurants, beach restaurants and cafes.

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :ads, only: [ :index, :show ] do
        collection do
          get 'restaurant', to: 'ads#restaurant'
          get 'beach_restaurant', to: 'ads#beach_restaurant'
          get 'cafe', to: 'ads#cafe'
        end
      end
    end
  end
  root to: 'pages#home'
```

Here's what I did in the api controller:

```
class Api::V1::AdsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_action :set_ad, only: [ :show ]

  def index
    @ads = policy_scope(Subcategory.find_by(nombre: "Restaurantes").ads)
  end

  def restaurant
    @restaurants = policy_scope(Subcategory.find_by(nombre: "Restaurantes").ads)
  end

  def beach_restaurant
    @beach_restaurants = policy_scope(Subcategory.find_by(nombre: "Restaurantes de playa").ads)
  end

  def cafe
    @cafes = policy_scope(Subcategory.find_by(nombre: "Cafés y Heladerías").ads)
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def set_ad
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    authorize @ad
  end
end
```

This is in my BaseController:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
  include Pundit

  after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:index, :restaurant, :beach_restaurant, :cafe]
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: [:index, :restaurant, :beach_restaurant, :cafe]

  rescue_from StandardError,                with: :internal_server_error
  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError,   with: :user_not_authorized
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

  private

  def user_not_authorized(exception)
    render json: {
      error: "Unauthorized #{exception.policy.class.to_s.underscore.camelize}.#{exception.query}"
    }, status: :unauthorized
  end

  def not_found(exception)
    render json: { error: exception.message }, status: :not_found
  end

  def internal_server_error(exception)
    if Rails.env.development?
      response = { type: exception.class.to_s, message: exception.message, backtrace: exception.backtrace }
    else
      response = { error: "Internal Server Error" }
    end
    render json: response, status: :internal_server_error
  end
end
```

And then I made the 3 different views: restaurant.json.jbuilder, beach_restaurant.json.jbuilder and cafe.json.jbuilder

`restaurant.json.jbuilder`

```
json.array! @restaurants do |restaurant|
  json.extract! restaurant,
  :id,
  :empresa,
  :direccion_principal,
  :tel,
  :email_principal,
  :web,
  :facebook,
  :instagram,
  :twitter,
  :isla
end
```

`beach_restaurant.json.jbuilder`

```
json.array! @beach_restaurants do |beach_restaurant|
  json.extract! beach_restaurant,
  :id,
  :empresa,
  :direccion_principal,
  :tel,
  :email_principal,
  :web,
  :facebook,
  :instagram,
  :twitter,
  :isla
end
```

`cafe.json.jbuilder`

```
json.array! @cafes do |cafe|
  json.extract! cafe,
  :id,
  :empresa,
  :direccion_principal,
  :tel,
  :email_principal,
  :web,
  :facebook,
  :instagram,
  :twitter,
  :isla
end
```

These 3 actions work fine when I request them on the local server with Postman, but once deployed on Heroku the cafe action creates an internal server error (status: 500). I can't see how it's possible because cafe is setup just in the same way as the the restaurant and beach_restaurant action and these 2 work on heroku. Does someone have an idea why this is the case?

This is what `heroku logs --tail` shows:

```
2018-12-04T06:19:38.704997+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/v1/ads/cafe" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=97694e3f-91fe-41fc-b2fc-de96d41d134d fwd="83.54.89.18" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=470ms status=500 bytes=274 protocol=https
2018-12-04T06:19:38.578597+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-12-04T06:19:38.578458 #4] DEBUG -- : [97694e3f-91fe-41fc-b2fc-de96d41d134d]    (41.7ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
2018-12-04T06:19:38.703397+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-12-04T06:19:38.701104 #4] DEBUG -- : [97694e3f-91fe-41fc-b2fc-de96d41d134d]   Subcategory Load (39.7ms)  SELECT  `subcategorias`.* FROM `subcategorias` WHERE `subcategorias`.`nombre` = 'Cafés y Heladerías' LIMIT 1
2018-12-04T06:19:38.703401+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-12-04T06:19:38.702341 #4]  INFO -- : [97694e3f-91fe-41fc-b2fc-de96d41d134d] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 462ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 121.7ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using .find() in the controller instead of .find_by(). I guess that somehow looking for the string name of the category fails when it's on Heroku. Looking up the category by its id is in this case better.

So the correct way is:

```
def beach_restaurant
    @cafes = policy_scope(Subcategory.find(3).ads)
end
```